# If I set a break point in Keydown event, the key I typed won't be appended to the text box

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

This is my test page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ()
        {
            $("#myInput").keydown(function ()
            {
                return; //(X)
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" />
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript should not interfere user input, but if I open developer console and set a break point in Keydown event at (X), the key I typed won't be appended to the text box. The same happens in Chrome 44.0.2403.155 m and Firefox 39.0.3, but not IE 10.

Is it a known feature or bug? Did I miss anything?

[image: I typed "1" into the text box, the break point is hit.]
Figure 1: I typed "1" into the text box, the break point is hit.

[image: I then click Continue, the "1" I typed doesn't show in the text box.]
Figure 2: I then click Continue, the "1" I typed doesn't show in the text box.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the return statement.

```
$("#myInput").keydown(function (e) {
  console.log( e.type );
} );
```

The return statement without a value is returning undefined which is being interpreted by jQuery as false. When you return false in a jQuery event handler it's like you called:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Those two lines will stop the browser's default reaction to the event, which is to put the key's value into the input.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted; using `return;` still allows the character input to appear, whereas `return false;` does not.  What the OP is asking about is the breakpoint in the handler not behaving in the same way.

Comment: Apologies for not understanding the OP's actual question. Odd behavior indeed. I confirmed that this issue can be seen outside of jQuery as well:

var el = document.getElementById("myInput");
el.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  return;
});

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer, but rather a confirmation that I'm seeing the same thing...

It appears to behave similarly to `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();` for keydown with or without a return, but with keypress it appears to behave differently.

Interestingly, if you press "tab" it hits the breakpoint, then focuses on the next input, so it appears that it continues to execute normally after the breakpoint.  But if you input a character, it does not execute and add that character to the input.

I also added tests for vanilla JavaScript `onkeydown` and `addEventListener`, which exhibit the same symptom.

`debugger;` is similar to adding a breakpoint in Chrome, and with the dev tools open it should pause.

```js
var $down = $('.keydown input');
$down.eq(0).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("keydown return;");
  return;
});
$down.eq(1).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("keydown return true;");
  return true;
});
$down.eq(2).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("keydown return false;");
  return false;
});
$down.eq(3).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("keydown e.preventDefault();");
  e.preventDefault();
});
$down.eq(4).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("keydown debugger;");
  debugger;
});
$down.get(5).onkeydown = function(){
  console.log("onkeydown debugger;");
  debugger;
};
$down.get(6).addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  console.log("keydown addEventListener debugger;");
  debugger;
});


var $up = $('.keyup input');
$up.eq(0).on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log("keyup return;");
  return;
});
$up.eq(1).on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log("keyup return true;");
  return true;
});
$up.eq(2).on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log("keyup return false;");
  return false;
});
$up.eq(3).on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log("keyup e.preventDefault();");
  e.preventDefault();
});
$up.eq(4).on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log("keyup debugger;");
  debugger;
});
$up.get(5).onkeyup = function(){
  console.log("onkeyup debugger;");
  debugger;
};
$up.get(6).addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  console.log("keyup addEventListener debugger;");
  debugger;
});


var $press = $('.keypress input');
$press.eq(0).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log("keypress return;");
  return;
});
$press.eq(1).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log("keypress return true;");
  return true;
});
$press.eq(2).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log("keypress return false;");
  return false;
});
$press.eq(3).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log("keypress e.preventDefault();");
  e.preventDefault();
});
$press.eq(4).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log("keypress debugger;");
  debugger;
});
$press.get(5).onkeypress = function(){
  console.log("onkeypress debugger;");
  debugger;
};
$press.get(6).addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  console.log("keypress addEventListener debugger;");
  debugger;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="keydown">
  <h1>On keydown...</h1>
  <p>return; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>return true; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>return false; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>e.preventDefault(); <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; (onkeydown)<input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; (addEventListener) <input type="text" /></p>
</div>

<div class="keyup">
  <h1>On keyup...</h1>
  <p>return; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>return true; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>return false; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>e.preventDefault(); <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; (onkeyup)<input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; (addEventListener) <input type="text" /></p>
</div>

<div class="keypress">
  <h1>On keypress...</h1>
  <p>return; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>return true; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>return false; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>e.preventDefault(); <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; <input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; (onkeypress)<input type="text" /></p>
  <p>debugger; (addEventListener) <input type="text" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks professional but it didn't solve my problem. With a breakpoint at `console.log("keyup return;")`, my input doesn't show; without the breakpoint, my input does show. Can you explain this?

Comment: Actually in all of your keydown tests, as long as there is a breakpoint in the event handler, no input will show.

Comment: @LoveRight that was my point; the debugger is the issue, not whatever is along with it (i.e what you're returning).  I agree it doesn't solve it, but it was too much to add into a comment.  The debugger does not seem to be an issue blocking the input in keyup or keypress however, only keydown, which is interesting...

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the clarification. Feel free to add more to the answer if you have more findings.